# Restrict dragging of div based on css class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the below code to arrange my divs :

```
$( ".myDivs" ).sortable({
    connectWith: [".myDivs"]
});
```

Is it possible to amend this code so as to exclude divs that can be sorted(moved) which contain a particualar css value :

```
<div class="myDivs excludeThisCss"><Excluded From Move></div>
```

Comment: I don't see the `.myDivs` in there... what you have, hard to tell, it is! :)

Comment: @Zuul apologies, ive updated my question

Comment: Can't you just remove the myDivs class from them? Or give the ones you want moved a new class?

Comment: @user470184, just added to the answer a working Fiddle Example to better illustrate the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to target the `myDivs` class that don't have the `excludeThisCss` class:

See this working [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/J5Hfd/)

**HTML FOR THE EXAMPLE**

```
<div class="connected">
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 01</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 02</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 03</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 04</div>
</div>

<div class="connected">
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 01</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 02</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 03</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 04</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".connected" ).sortable({
        connectWith : ".connected",
        items       : ".myDivs:not(.excludeThisCss)"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

On the Fiddle example, you will be able to drag all `.myDivs` items, but the ones with `.excludeMe` class will not move!